# sign up in Instagram with python

Tags: python, selenium, instagram

Is there any way to signup to Instagram with Python selenium/requests or anything else? I've used selenium before but can't even select drop down lists in HTML for date of birth!

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I will give you a hint, first click on the dropdown list with:

`driver.find_element(By.XPATH, 'dropdown list xpath').click()`

and then you will be able to see the date html and select/click on it, repeat for day month and year

If you can't find the dropdown list html, inspect element, click on the mouse on a box icon and click on the dropdown list, it will automatically show you the html code position. Then you can also right-click, copy and then copy XPATH to directly get the xpath.